# Parsing Time From json. Specific Format

Tags: android, json

I receive the below JSON and i am able to parse through the Description and date. I have been trying to parse through the time but everything that i try keeps giving me bad output.

The time object is supposed to say 5:30 but i do not know if i am able to parse through that format. I thought it was `public String format3339 (boolean allDay)`
I have posted the JSON Input, my JSON parsing, and the output.

Input

```
{"object":[{"description":"blah blah blah","date":"2012-12-11","time":"2000-01-01T05:30:00Z"}]}
```

Mainly i am worried about `"time":"2000-01-01T05:30:00Z"`

Parsing

```
JSONArray arr = null;
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject d = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    Time time = new Time();
    String etime = d.getString(TIME_TAG);
    String description = d.getString(DESCRIPTION_TAG);
    String date = d.getString(DATE_TAG);
            //************************************************************************
            //********I suspect that i might be converting the time object incorrectly but whatever 
            //********i put here either does not work or gives me bad output. 
    Boolean mtime = time.parse3339(etime);
    if (mtime == true) {
        etime = time.toString();
    }
            //************************************************************************
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(DATE_TAG, date);
    map.put(DESCRIPTION_TAG, description);
    map.put(TIME_TAG, etime);

    list.add(map);
```

OutPut- I do not understand this output I thought that the input was 3339 format but the output is difficult to work with. I guess i could make a parser to parse out the 530 from the string given but i thought my output would be YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS format from the toString() operation.

```
20000101T053000UTC(0,0,0,-1,946704600)
```

EDIT::Here is what i hacked together to get what i want with little effort. It works for now.

```
JSONArray arr = null;
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject d = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String etime = d.getString(TIME_TAG);
    String description = d.getString(DESCRIPTION_TAG);
    String date = d.getString(DATE_TAG);

        if (eTime.charAt(11) == '0')
    eTime = eTime.substring(12, 16);
    else
    eTime = eTime.substring(11, 16);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(DATE_TAG, date);
    map.put(DESCRIPTION_TAG, description);
    map.put(TIME_TAG, etime);

    list.add(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve most Json format problems is to go vise versa: Create your Time, convert to Json Object and investigate String representation. I think you will find your issue quickly.

About your problem: `DateTime` format you posted is ISO 8601. JSON does not specify this  format for dates/times.

You can try to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to get proper Date type that Json can parse.

Or [ISO time format](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html)

Or other pretty good way to use `GSON` library.

Comment: Ok So i think is see what you are getting at. The closest accepted time format is a string that looks like `"2008-10-13T16:00:00.000Z"` My input is missing the last 3 ints. `2000-01-01-T05:30:00Z` Does that mean that i am just not able to parse this format? If that is the case then i think i might hack it together by deleting last char and adding a `+ ".000Z"`

Comment: @doubleA Right, for sure `.000Z` is absent but from my exp. you still can't parse it. Before, convert it to  appropriate date form

Comment: I ended up just making it work for what i need. I posted my edit above. I might go back and change it later but for now it is working the way that i want it to. Thankyou for your assistance good sir. ---you are right by the way, Even deleting the last char and adding the `.000Z` does not put the string in the correct format to be parsed. I wonder why this is. If the parser is indeed just parsing a string should it matter if it was created in a specific format?

Answer (score 0):

The time format you have is SQL. You can parse it using java.SQL.date class.